# How to retain sessionId within Live Agent

Tags: rest-api, liveagent, session

We're implementing a Salesforce LiveAgent chat for our website, and we want the chat to appear in the bottom right corner of the page, not a popup. My question is: is this even possible while retaining same chat functionality?

I have successfully implemented it on the bottom of the page by using a dialog and iframe. However, upon reloading/navigating through the website, the chat session is lost and visitors have to start all over again - which is pretty inconvenient. 
I am looking to somehow get the user session ID or any other way is that the chat stays open no  matter what page user navigates to.

How do I actually do it? Any help is much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using html button generated by salesforce? If yes - check [Live Agent Rest Api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_SessionId.htm?search_text=visitor)